# bootply bootstrap notification menu include a number at the upper right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I want to use this bootstrap notification menu

http://www.bootply.com/oasBuRC8Kz#

but need to include the number of notifications to the upper right of the glyphicon.  I read through the documentation for glyphicon.  I didn't see that option.  I want something similar to the option that linkein has with their menu options.  Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the documentation of glyphicon in :

http://getbootstrap.com/components/

And if you need the number in notifications go to badges:

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#badges

Just combine both to get the result:

https://jsfiddle.net/0rr2s5t5/

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>
 <span class="badge">4</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks.  But, I don't see in the documentation how to include a number on the upper right of the glyphicon like the LinkedIn menu items.